# Remove the Poly-lines on google map not working in Kotlin

Tags: java, kotlin, google-maps

I am trying to remove poly line's without using for loop. Most of the Solutions  are with for loop. if we are remove using for loop , then it will not removing the poly lines.

```
var polyline: Polyline? = null
polyline = mMap!!.addPolyline((PolylineOptions().addAll(listPolyArray).width(5f).color(requireActivity().getResources().getColor(R.color.green)).geodesic(true)))

polyline!!.remove()
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Can you please put together a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and add it to a git hosting provider (e.g. github, bitbucket, etc)? The easiest way to do this might be to fork the Google Maps Android API Samples Repository and modify one of the existing demo activities: 
https://github.com/googlemaps/android-samples 

Then you can list steps to reproduce the problem, so that the community might be able to help you better.